# Wrong favicon when i share the link of my react app

Tags: android, iphone, reactjs, web, favicon

I have a landing page write in react (with create-react-app), and i put as a favicon the logo of my app, but the problem is that when i share the link of that landing page by text message (SMS), the favicon is still the react icon instead of the favicon on my project repository.

I don't understand why because when i go to this link through my browser, it displays well my favicon.

Comment: Is the icon valid when you open http://my-site.com/favicon.ico (replace with your site address and favicon address). Did you share the link before? Maybe the favicon is just cached? Try opening the site with some parameter like http://www.my-site.com?v=2

Comment: Yes, when i open the website through the browser it displays the right logo, same for "/favicon.ico", but when i share the link by facebook or by SMS it display the react icon.